# Find a value that exceeds the 80th percentile?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I need to find the first number that exceeds x[floor(0.8*N)+1], when there is duplicate values within the array. but am unsure how to do this. x refers to an array on integers which have been sorted in ascending order. Help is much appreciated.

```
void eightypercentile(int x[], values)
{
  int eightiethpercentile;
  if( x[floor(0.9*N)+1] <= x[floor(0.8*N)])
  {
    eightiethpercentile = /*first number that exceeds x[floor(0.8*N)+1] */
  }
  int eightiethpercentile = x[floor(0.8*N)+1];

}
```

Comment: This discussion might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553970/find-the-first-element-in-an-array-that-is-greater-than-the-target

Comment: Is `values` the number of values in the array? (it better be...).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do:

```
nc = ceil(N * 0.8)
nf = floor(N * 0.8)
if (nc == nf) nc++;
while (x[nc] == x[nc-1]) 
  nc++;
return x[nc];
```