# Binary search bounds

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

I always have the hardest time with this and I have yet to see a definitive explanation for something that is supposedly so common and highly-used.

We already know the standard binary search. Given starting lower and upper bounds, find the middle point at (lower + higher)/2, and then compare it against your array, and then re-set the bounds accordingly, etc.

However what are the needed differences to adjust the search to find (for a list in ascending order):

1. Smallest value >= target
2. Smallest value > target
3. Largest value <= target
4. Largest value < target

It seems like each of these cases requires very small tweaks to the algorithm but I can never get them to work right. I try changing inequalities, return conditions, I change how the bounds are updated, but nothing seems consistent.

What are the definitive ways to handle these four cases?

Comment: I don't understand the question; are 'Smallest value' and 'Largest value' the values in the leftmost and rightmost positions of the array, respectively?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? It seems like a weird thing to ask otherwise.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Not at all. It's just an issue I run into again and again and again.

Comment: @Codor Yes, sorry. Assume that the array is sorted in ascending order.

Comment: Are you asking how it works if the target is not in the array...?

Comment: @JesseShellabarger No.

Comment: Then what do you mean by smallest value>target? Seems to me that if you're looking for something smaller than the arrays smallest value...it must not be there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binary search(at least the way I implement it) relies on a simple property - a predicate holds true for one end of the interval and does not hold true for the other end. I always consider my interval to be closed at one end and opened at the other. So let's take a look at this code snippet:

```
int beg = 0; // pred(beg) should hold true
int end = n;// length of an array or a value that is guranteed to be out of the interval that we are interested in

while (end - beg >  1) {
  int mid = (end + beg) / 2;
  if (pred(a[mid])) {
    beg = mid;
  } else { 
    end = mid;
  }
}
// answer is at a[beg]
```

This will work for any of the comparisons you define. Simply replace `pred` with `<=target` or `>=target` or `<target` or `>target`.

After the cycle exits, `a[beg]` will be the last element for which the given inequality holds.

So let's assume(like suggested in the comments) that we want to find the largest number for which `a[i] <= target`. Then if we use predicate `a[i] <= target` the code will look like:

```
int beg = 0; // pred(beg) should hold true
int end = n;// length of an array or a value that is guranteed to be out of the interval that we are interested in
while (end - beg >  1) {
  int mid = (end + beg) / 2;
  if (a[mid] <= target) {
    beg = mid;
  } else { 
    end = mid;
  }
}
```

And after the cycle exits, the index that you are searching for will be  `beg`.

Also depending on the comparison you may have to start from the right end of the array. E.g. if you are searching for the largest value >= target, you will do something of the sort of:

```
beg = -1;
end = n - 1;
while (end - beg >  1) {
  int mid = (end + beg) / 2;
  if (a[mid] >= target) {
    end = mid;
  } else { 
    beg = mid;
  }
}
```

And the value that you are searching for will be with index `end`. Note that in this case I consider the interval `(beg, end]` and thus I've slightly modified the starting interval.

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example predicate to more clearly illustrate what you mean?

Comment: well I suggest samples in the last sentence. If you replace `pred(a[mid])` with `a[mid] <= target` you will find the largest number `<= target` for instance. The important point in my answer is  - always think in this direction - something is true for one end of the interval and is not true for the other. You want to find the point where the "truthness" changes its value.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your point but I tried this and it didn't seem to work. For example if I want the first/smallest value >= some target, my predicate would be: if a[mid]>=target, beg = mid, else end = mid, correct?

Comment: I think my previous comment was a bit misleading. Actually in this case you want the first value for which ` val < target` *does not hold true*, thus the predicate that is true for `beg` and not true for `end` is in fact `a[mid] < target` and this is what you should use.

Comment: So the predicate must be false? Aren't there several ways to do that? I think this is probably a powerful answer but I simply do not understand the approach

Comment: Also I just tried a[mid] < target and the result is still inaccurate

Comment: In what sense is it inaccurate. Could you provide a specific example?

Comment: [12, 23, 30, 32], target 13. Smallest number larger than this is 23, algorithm gives me 12.

Comment: @user4992519 I see and it makes perfect sense. My algorithm makes sure that the value with index `beg` is such that the predicate holds true for it. Thus the first value for which the predicate does not hold true is in fact the next value in the array(take care to check the case when there is no such number).

Comment: so the predicate `a[val] < target` means the answer `a[beg]` will be the maximal value for which it holds, so `beg+1` will be the index of the first `value >= target`? So let's say I wanted the largest `value < target`. Does this mean my predicate is now searching for `a[mid] >= target`, and then at the end, `a[beg]` is one position ahead of the value I want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80410/discussion-between-ivaylo-strandjev-and-user4992519).

Answer (score 18):

I figured out loop invariants along with predicates are the best and most consistent way of approaching all binary problems.

Point 1: **Think of predicates** 
In general for all these 4 cases (and also the normal binary search for equality), imagine them as a predicate. So what this means is that some of the values are meeting the predicate and some some failing. So consider for example this array with a target of 5:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]. Finding the first number greater than 5 is basically equivalent of finding the first one in this array: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1].

Point 2: **Search boundaries inclusive** 
I like to have both ends always inclusive. But I can see some people like start to be inclusive and end exclusive (on len instead of len -1). I like to have all the elements inside of the array, so when referring to a[mid] I don't think whether that will give me an array out of bound. So my preference: Go inclusive!!!

Point 3: **While loop condition <=**
So we even want to process the subarray of size 1 in the while loop, and when the while loop finishes there should be no unprocessed element. I really like this logic. It's always solid as a rock. Initially all the elements are not inspected, basically they are unknown. Meaning that everything in the range of [st = 0, to end = len - 1] are not inspected. Then when the while loop finishes, the range of uninspected elements should be array of size 0!

Point 4: **Loop invariants**
Since we defined start = 0, end = len - 1, invariants will be like this:
Anything left of start is smaller than target.
Anything right of end is greater than or equal to the target.

Point 5: **The answer**
Once the loop finishes, basically based on the loop invariants anything to the left of start is smaller. So that means that start is the first element greater than or equal to the target.
Equivalently, anything to the right of end is greater than or equal to the target. So that means the answer is also equal to end + 1.

The code:

```
public int find(int a[], int target){
  int start = 0; 
  int end = a.length - 1; 
  while (start <= end){
    int mid = (start + end) / 2; // or for no overflow start + (end - start) / 2
    if (a[mid] < target) 
       start = mid + 1; 
    else // a[mid] >= target
       end = mid - 1; 
  }
  return start; // or end + 1;
}
```

variations:
**<** 
It's equivalent of finding the first 0. So basically only return changes.

```
return end; // or return start - 1;
```

**>** 
change the if condition to <= and else will be >. No other change.

**<=** 
Same as >, `return end; // or return start - 1;`

So in general with this model for all the 5 variations (<=, <, >, >=, normal binary search) only the condition in the if changes and the return statement. And figuring those small changes is super easy when you consider the invariants (point 4) and the answer (point 5).

After understanding this method, everything for binary search should be as clear as day!

Extra point: It would be a good practice to also try including the start but excluding the end. So the array would be initially [0, len). If you can write the invariants, new condition for the while loop, the answer and then a clear code, it means you learnt the concept.

Answer (score 0):

The basic binary search is to search the position/value which equals with the target key. While it can be extended to ***find the minimal position/value which satisfy some condition***, or ***find the maximal position/value which satisfy some condition***.

Suppose the array is ascending order, if no satisfied position/value found, return -1.

Code sample:

```
  // find the minimal position which satisfy some condition
  private static int getMinPosition(int[] arr, int target) {
      int l = 0, r = arr.length - 1;
      int ans = -1;
      while(l <= r) {
          int m = (l + r) >> 1;
          // feel free to replace the condition
          // here it means find the minimal position that the element not smaller than target
          if(arr[m] >= target) {
              ans = m;
              r = m - 1;
          } else {
              l = m + 1;
          }
      }
      return ans;
  }

  // find the maximal position which satisfy some condition
  private static int getMaxPosition(int[] arr, int target) {
      int l = 0, r = arr.length - 1;
      int ans = -1;
      while(l <= r) {
          int m = (l + r) >> 1;
          // feel free to replace the condition
          // here it means find the maximal position that the element less than target
          if(arr[m] < target) {
              ans = m;
              l = m + 1;
          } else {
              r = m - 1;
          }
      }
      return ans;
  }

    int[] a = {3, 5, 5, 7, 10, 15};
    System.out.println(BinarySearchTool.getMinPosition(a, 5));
    System.out.println(BinarySearchTool.getMinPosition(a, 6));
    System.out.println(BinarySearchTool.getMaxPosition(a, 8));
```

Comment: @user4992519 Could you paste your test case?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a binary search that lets you participate in the process at the last step. The typical binary search would receive `(array, element)` and produce a value (normally the index or *not found*). But if you have a modified binary that accept a function to be invoked at the end of the search you can cover all cases.

For example, in Javascript to make it easy to test, the following binary search

```
function binarySearch(array, el, fn) {
    function aux(left,  right) {
        if (left > right) {
            return fn(array, null, left, right);
        }

        var middle = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
        var value = array[middle];

        if (value > el) {
            return aux(left, middle - 1);
        } if (value < el) {
            return aux(middle + 1, right);
        } else {
            return fn(array, middle, left, right);
        }
    }

    return aux(0, array.length - 1);
}
```

would allow you to cover each case with a particular return function.

- default
  `function(a, m) { return m; }`
- Smallest value >= target
  `function(a, m, l, r) { return m != null ? a[m] : r + 1 >= a.length ? null : a[r + 1]; }`
- Smallest value > target
  `function(a, m, l, r) { return (m || r) + 1 >= a.length ? null : a[(m || r) + 1]; }`
- Largest value <= target
  `function(a, m, l, r) { return m != null ? a[m] : l - 1 > 0 ? a[l - 1] : null; }`
- Largest value < target
  `function(a, m, l, r) { return (m || l) - 1 < 0 ? null : a[(m || l) - 1]; }`