# Calculating distance between element of two arrays

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have 2 arrays `A[]` and `B[]` with n elements each , I want to calculate the difference between each element of `A` array to the element of `B` array, and output is the set of Elements with difference less than `x0` (some value).

For ex : `A =[1,2,3] B=[2,3,4]`
I want `"1-2","1-3","1-4","2-3" ...`

say `x0 = 2`, So the output be `([1,2],[1,3],[2,3]...)`.
I'm using the brute force approach ,taking each element of array `A` and subtracting with `B`'s element  which has time complexity of `O(n^2)`. Can anyone suggest better approach ?

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of this problem is [output-sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output-sensitive_algorithm), meaning, if all possible pairs match, then the alogirhtm must run `O(n^2)` time. Assuming the output is smaller then `O(n*log(n))`, the following python code runtime is `O(n*log(n))`:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right
from itertools import repeat

arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
arr2 = sorted([2, 3, 4, 5])

d = 1

result = []
for item in arr1:
    left, right = bisect_left(arr2, item - d), bisect_right(arr2, item + d)
    result += zip(repeat(item), arr2[left:right])
```

The code above sorts one of the arrays, and then searches the other one items from in the sorted one. This requires `O(n*log(n))` time for sorting one of the arrays, and then `O(log(n))` for bisecting the array for each search.

Answer (score 0):

Find pairs: `(Ai, Bi) where Ai - Bi < X0,`

Now,

```
   Ai - Bi < X0,
=> Ai - X0 < Bi
```

That means that any element in `B` which value greater than `(Ai - X0)` would result in `Ai - Bi < X0`

So basically, You have to search for elements in `B` which are greater than some other value, say `P`.

You can easily search elements in sorted array in `O(lgN)` time. In this case, you will need modified binary search which finds index of values greater than given value.

Here is how you can achieve that: [(Click Here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553970/find-the-first-element-in-a-sorted-array-that-is-greater-than-the-target)

Here is the complete algorithm:

```
getPairs(A,B,X0)
    sort(B)
    pairs = []
    for each element Ai in A do:
        P = Ai - X0
        index = modifiedBinarySearch(B, P)
        while ( index < B.length ) do
            pairs.push( { Ai, Bindex } )
            index++
        done
    done
    return pairs
done
```

Time Complexity:

```
Sorting array of N elements:        O(NlgN)
Iterating over array of N elements: O(N)
The inner while loop:               O(N)

Thus, overall complexity:           O(NlgN)
```

If you are not sure about how inner while loop takes, O(N), let me know in comments.